# lineinfile is skipped if one of the task failed

Tags: ansible

This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_unreachable: true

  tasks:
  - command: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - "ls" 
      - "df -h"
    register: files
    ignore_errors: true
  - name: delegate
    command: ls
    register: files2
    delegate_to: "{{item}}"
    ignore_errors: true
    with_items:
      - "{{groups['test_servers1']}}"
  - lineinfile:
      line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      path: /tmp/list.log
      create: yes
    when:
      - item.changed is defined
      - item.changed
    loop: "{{ files.results + 
          files2.results}}"
```

**TEST 1**:
Using this inventory:

```
192.168.153.31
#[test_servers1]
```

Output:

```
TASK [command] **************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.153.31] => (item=ls)
changed: [192.168.153.31] => (item=df -h)

TASK [delegate] **************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.153.31]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'test_servers1'"}
...ignoring
TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.153.31]
```

**TEST2**:
Using this inventory:

```
192.168.153.31
[test_servers1]
```

Output:

```
TASK [command] *************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.153.31] => (item=ls)
changed: [192.168.153.31] => (item=df -h)

TASK [delegate] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.153.31] => {
    "files2": {
        "changed": false,
        "results": [],
        "skipped": true,
        "skipped_reason": "No items in the list"
    }
}

TASK [lineinfile] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.153.31] => (item={'start': '2021-07-18 02:11:13.080046', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_par..........
```

Question 1:
Since the inventory in the first test doesn't contain `test_servers1` group, the task is ignored. But why is `lineinfile` skipped even though `file` contains `results`?

Question 2:
In TEST2, my `delegate` task contains only one command i.e., `ls` why has `file2` `results`? As per my knowledge when looping through multiple commands only `register variable contains results`.

Question 3:
Is it possible to check if `files2` contains `results` in the `lineinfile` module, and if yes to check if `files2.results` is not empty then only loop through it, but skip it otherwise?

Comment: Use ``when: item.changed|default(false)`` This will cover both the definition and the positivity tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is, that `files2` does not contain a field `results` as the task where it comes from threw an error, but you try to concatenate `files.results` and `files2.results`, which fails as `files2.results` does not exist. If you add this to your playbook:

```yaml
  - name: files2
    debug:
      msg: "{{ files2 }}"
  - name: files + files2
    debug:
      msg: "{{ files.results + files2.results }}"
```

You'll see the error:

```
TASK [files2] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": {
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'test_servers1'"
    }
}

TASK [files + files2] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'results'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/tommy/test/a.yml': line 23, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      msg: \"{{ files2 }}\"\n  - name: files + files2\n    ^ here\n"}
```

So the result from `"{{ files.results + files2.results }}"` is non-existent and the task is skipped.

The answer to the second part of your question is, that the output of a task with a loop will always have this structure, no matter if you loop over 0, 1 or 100 items in the list. It will always have `results`, but `results` will be empty if you iterated over a list without elements.

The answer to part three is, instead of using complicated `when` conditions, you should just add a `lineinfile` task per list you want to write to the file, like this:

```yaml
  - lineinfile:
      line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      path: /tmp/list.log
      create: yes
    when:
      - item.changed is defined
      - item.changed
    loop: "{{ files.results }}" 
  - lineinfile:
      line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      path: /tmp/list.log
      create: yes
    when:
      - item.changed is defined
      - item.changed
    loop: "{{ files2.results | default([]) }}"
```